# Suspicious behaviour of twistd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bandwidth, ubuntu-11.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop with all the latest updates.

For the last two days I've been observing that my network traffic is showing 100% usage (max bandwidth) even when all the browsers are closed. When I checked the system manager, twistd is in the top four processes (memory and CPU usage). After killing twistd, everything is normal.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Why is `twistd` running? What does it do?